# How can i make my android app open another app?

Tags: java, android

So i have the down code and the app still does not open the app i want.
It does not give any error on the try catch and says it open the app.
Is it something about android api 29?

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class StartOnBootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String PREF_SELECTED_APP_PACKAGE = "selected_app_package";
    private static final String TAG = "StartOnBootUpReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action) ||
                Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action) ||
                Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(action)) {

            // Retrieve the selected app's package name from SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String selectedAppPackage = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_SELECTED_APP_PACKAGE, null);

            if (selectedAppPackage != null) {
                PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                Intent launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(selectedAppPackage);
                if (launchIntent != null) {
                    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    try {
                        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
                        Log.d(TAG, "App launched: " + selectedAppPackage);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error launching app: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Launch intent is null for package: " + selectedAppPackage);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Selected app package is null.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried also make it by a background service but it still didnt work.
I already have the on boot complete permission.

Comment: IS this a BroadcastReceiver?  If so, a BroadcastReceiver can no longer start a foreground process.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: Yes it is, what should i do to make it work? But right now im not using a foreground service

Comment: If you want your app to start when the device starts, create a launcher.

Comment: Do you have any resource?